# Windows Event Collector between workgroup

Tags: windows, windows-event-log

I  configured a windows server 2016 in workgroup as windows event collector in "source computer initiated" mode. I added in the subscription configuration another windows server 2016, also in workgroup, as "non-domain computers".

I generated the certificates for 'authentication via PowerShell and they are self-signed.

Below is info regarding the client configuration.

The command line test works correctly:

`Test-WSMan -ComputerName WIN-87QJVNB1SBN -Authentication ClientCertificate -CertificateThumbprint 85C8833356B5D6ADB2 D7BFDC2764D50ECFA49854`

wsmid           : http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/identity/1/wsmanidentity.xsd

ProtocolVersion : http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/1/wsman.xsd

ProductVendor   : Microsoft Corporation
ProductVersion  : OS: 10.0.14393 SP: 0.0 Stack: 3.0

My question is: is it possible to configure WEC between client/server in workgroup without the help of a domain controller or is this configuration not supported?

Thanks